# HTTP request failed when using Twitter API with simplexml_load_file

Tags: twitter, simplexml, php

I want to display the 5 last tweet of a twitter account in a list

```
if(($xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=5&screen_name=les_sismo')) !== FALSE) {
    $tweets = $xml->xpath("/statuses/status");

     foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
         $text = $tweet->text;
         echo '<li>' . $text . '</li>';
     }
}
else echo 'error';
```

And all I got is 2 Warning

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=5&screen_name=les_sismo) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /homez.466/sismodes/www/wp-content/themes/sismo/header.php on line 89

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=5&screen_name=les_sismo" in /homez.466/sismodes/www/wp-content/themes/sismo/header.php on line 89
error
```

Answer (score 3):

Twitter has a pretty strict limit on API calls, if you've exceeded that limit you'll get a 400 Bad Request error. For more info on this see: [Rate Limiting FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/faq)

To get around this you could check the HTTP header for a positive response.

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/les_sismo.xml?count=5";
$url_headers = @get_headers($url);
if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
} else {
  // Error
  exit("failed to load XML");
}
```

To get around periods where the xml is not accessible due to insufficient available API calls, you could perhaps cache the xml file locally and call on that as a fallback in the else statement above.